# Incrementor logic

Tags: java, logic, post-increment, pre-increment

I'm trying to get deeper with post and pre incrementors but am a bit stuck with the following expression :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = 0;
    i = i+=(++i + (i+=2 + --i) - ++i);
    // i = 0 + (++i + (i+=2 + --i) - ++i);
    // i = 0 + (1   + (3    +   2) -  1 );
    // i = 0 + (6                  -  1 );
    System.out.println(i); // Prints 0 instead of 5
}
```

I know I'm missing the logic somewhere but where?

What I've tried :

- Going from left to right (though I know it is not recommended)
- Going from the insidest bracket and starting from there.

Thanks for the help

PS : The comments are the details of my calculus

**EDIT 1**

I tried to change de hard coded value from the expression from `2` to something else and the result always gives `0`

Look at this example :

```
    int i = 0;
    i = i+=(++i + (i+=32500 + --i) - ++i);
    System.out.println(i); // Prints 0
```

This expression should logically be nowhere near `0` but somehow it does print it.

The same happens when I use a negative :

```
    int i = 0;
    i = i+=(++i + (i+=(-32650) + --i) - ++i);
    System.out.println(i); // Prints 0
```

---

**EDIT 2**

Now, I changed the value of `i` to begin with :

```
    int i = 1;
    i = i+=(++i + (i+=2 + --i) - ++i);
    System.out.println(i); // Prints 2
    
    i = 2;
    i = i+=(++i + (i+=10000 + --i) - ++i);
    System.out.println(i); // Prints 4
    
    i = 3;
    i = i+=(++i + (i+=(-32650) + --i) - ++i);
    System.out.println(i); // Prints 6
```

It gives the double of `i` each time, whatever the hard coded value is.

Comment: could you eleborate why you think it´s `5` instead of `0`

Comment: The comments in the code are my calculs

Comment: Ahh didn´t catch that

Comment: well going from left to right won't solve it.. the compilers convert normal expressions to [reverse polish notations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) and evaluates them and then constructs a **expression tree** and solves the expression.

Comment: so simply going from left to right or insidest won't give you the result program will generate

Comment: If you "know it is not recommended" why did you do it anyway? Why not do it the recommended way?

Comment: @Thomas and what is the recommended way? That's the point right here.

Comment: @Thomas This is simply curiosity indeed. I want to understand everything I'm learning.

Comment: Can anyone confirm the first example actually returns `0`? Running the code on 1.6, I got result of `3`.

Comment: @JiriTousek this is interesting ! Did you copy paste it?

Comment: @Yassin I did. I got even more confusing results when I replaced one or both of the `i +=` with `i = i +` - replacing one of them (don't remember which) led to result `4`, replacing the other didn't change the result.

Comment: Would you mind do a printscreen and post it?

Comment: @JiriTousek I compiled with 1.4, then ran with following versions, and all produced `0`: 1.4.2_19, 1.5.0_22, 1.6.0_45, 1.7.0_79, 1.8.0_51 on Windows 7, Sun/Oracle JVMs.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Quoting [Java Language Specification, 15.7 Evaluation Order](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7):

> The Java programming language guarantees that the operands of operators appear to be evaluated in a specific evaluation order, namely, from **left to right**.
>
> The **left-hand operand** of a binary operator appears to be **fully evaluated** before any part of the right-hand operand is evaluated.
>
> If the operator is a **compound-assignment operator** ([§15.26.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2)), then evaluation of the left-hand operand includes both remembering the variable that the left-hand operand denotes and **fetching and saving that variable's value** for use in the implied binary operation.

So, essentially, `i += ++i` will remember the old value of `i` on the left side, *before* evaluating the right side.

Remember, *evaluation order* of operands and *precedence* of operators are two different things.

Showing evaluation order, step by step, with saved value in {braces}:

```
int i = 0;
i    = i    += (++i + (i    += 2 + --i) - ++i); // i = 0
i{0} = i    += (++i + (i    += 2 + --i) - ++i); // i = 0
i{0} = i{0} += (++i + (i    += 2 + --i) - ++i); // i = 0
i{0} = i{0} += (1   + (i    += 2 + --i) - ++i); // i = 1
i{0} = i{0} += (1   + (i{1} += 2 + --i) - ++i); // i = 1
i{0} = i{0} += (1   + (i{1} += 2 + 0  ) - ++i); // i = 0
i{0} = i{0} += (1   + (i{1} += 2      ) - ++i); // i = 0
i{0} = i{0} += (1   + 3                 - ++i); // i = 3
i{0} = i{0} += (4                       - ++i); // i = 3
i{0} = i{0} += (4                       - 4  ); // i = 4
i{0} = i{0} += 0                              ; // i = 4
i{0} = 0                                      ; // i = 0
0                                             ; // i = 0
```

**Followup to edits to question**

If we name the initial value `I` and the constant `N`:

```
int i = I;
i = i += (++i + (i += N + --i) - ++i);
```

Then we can see that the values are:

```
i{I} = i{I} += ((I+1) + (i{I+1} += N + I) - ((I+1+N+I)+1));
i{I} = i{I} += (I + 1 + (I + 1 + N + I) - (I + 1 + N + I + 1));
i{I} = i{I} += (I + 1 + I + 1 + N + I - I - 1 - N - I - 1);
i{I} = i{I} += I;
i{I} = I + I;
i = 2 * I;
```

Comment: Hi Andreas ! This seems to be an acceptable answer indeed but would you mind (if it is not too much asked) apply the same logic when i = something else and also when the hard coded value is bigger than 2 ? That would be awesome, I tried to do it but came with a wrong answer

Comment: @YassinHajaj Just did that. :-)

Comment: Thank you very much ! That is great !

Answer (score 5):

This is the logic taking into account your first edit (with an unknown `X`):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = 0;
    i = i+=(++i + (i+=X + --i) - ++i);
    // i = 0 += (++i + ((i += (X + --i)) - ++i));
    // i = 0 += (1 + ((i += (X + --i)) - ++i)); // i = 1
    // i = 0 += (1 + ((1 += (X + --i)) - ++i)); // i = 1 and i will then take the result of 1 += (X + --i)
    // i = 0 += (1 + ((1 += (X + 0)) - ++i)); // i = 0 and i will then take the result of 1 += (X + 0)
    // i = 0 += (1 + (X + 1 - ++i)); // i = X + 1
    // i = 0 += (1 + (X + 1 - X - 2)); // i = X + 2
    // i = 0 += (0); // i = X + 2
    // i = 0;
    System.out.println(i); // Prints 0
}
```

Tricks here:

- `+=` is an [assignement operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26) so it is right-associative: in the snippets, I added parenthesis to express this more clearly
- The result of the assignment expression is the value of the variable after the assignment has occurred
- The [postfix increment operator `++`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.14.2) and [postfix decrement operator `--`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.14.3) add or subtract 1 from the value and the result is stored back into the variable.
- The `+` [additive operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.2) first computes the left-hand operand then the right-hand operand.

For your second edit (with an unknown `I` added):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = I;
    i = i+=(++i + (i+=X + --i) - ++i);
    // i = I += (++i + ((i += (X + --i)) - ++i));
    // i = I += (I+1 + ((i += (X + --i)) - ++i)); // i = I+1
    // i = I += (I+1 + ((I+1 += (X + --i)) - ++i)); // i = I+1 and i will then take the result of I+1 += (X + --i)
    // i = I += (I+1 + ((I+1 += (X + I)) - ++i)); // i = I and i will then take the result of I+1 += (X + I)
    // i = I += (I+1 + (X+2*I+1 - ++i)); // i = X + 2*I + 1
    // i = I += (I+1 + (X+2*I+1 - X-2*I-2)); // i = X + 2*I + 2
    // i = I += (I); // i = X + 2*I + 2
    // i = 2 * I;
    System.out.println(i); // Prints 2 * I
}
```

Comment: following that logic, could you eleborate why `i = i+= (++i + (i+=2)) == i = i+= (++i + (i+=2 + --i)); = 4`

Comment: I'm editing the question because I came to something else really weird !

Comment: Hey @Tunaki, could you check the edit I made to the post. This logic does not apply anymore

Answer (score 4):

I suggest the following: format the code differently, so that there's only 1 statement per line, e.g.

```
@Test
public void test() {
    int i = 0;
    i = 
    i+=
    (
    ++i 
    + 
    (
    i+=
    2 
    + 
    --i
    ) 
    -
    ++i
    );
    System.out.println(i); // Prints 0 instead of 5
}
```

Then run it under the debugger and press F5 ("Step into") always. This will help you to understand in which order items get evaluated:

1. `int i=0;`
2. `i=`: ... (needs to wait for result of calculation A)
3. `i+=` ... (needs to wait B)
4. `++i`: i=1
5. `i+=` ... (needs to wait C)
6. `2+`
7. `--i`: i=0
8. ...: i=3 (result for wait C)
9. `-`
10. `++i`: i=4 and operand of - is also 4
11. ...: i=0 (result for wait B)
12. ...: i=0 (result for wait A)

Line 10 will always make the result of line 3 `0`, so the initial value of i will never be changed by the whole operation.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, let's break down every thing:

```
int i = 0; // i = 0, no big deal
```

Then starting into the most inner parenthesis:

```
(i+=2 + --i)
```

- it first decrement `i` and use the result (`-1`)
- then add 2 (`-1+2=1`)
- and add the result to i (which is 0 at the start of the operation) (`0+1=1=i`)

At the end, the first decrement is ignored by the reassignation.

Next parenthesis:

```
i+= (++i + previous_result - ++i)
```

- it increase the `i` ( with `++i`) at two points
- then the operation becomes `(i+1) + previous_result - (i+2)` (notice how the increment are not simultaneous) that gives `2 + 1 - 3 = 0`.
- the result of the operation is added to the initial `i` (`0`)

Again the increment will get discard by the reassignation.

finally:

```
i = previous_result
```

Which gives 0 :)

Comment: I'm editing the question because I came to something else really weird !

Answer (score 1):

Because of the highest precedence (...) will be evaluated first then ++ & -- and then remaining operators.
Your expression is like

```
i = i += ( (++i) + (i+=2 + (--i)) - (++i) );

//i = i = i + ( (++i) + (i+=2 + (--i)) - (++i) );
//i = i = 0 + ( (++i) + (i+=2 + (--i)) - (++i) );
//i = i = 0 + ( (1) + (i+=2 + (--i)) - (++i) );
//i = i = 0 + ( (1) + (i+=2 + (0)) - (++i) );
//i = i = 0 + ( (1) + (2 + (0)) - (++i) );
//i = i = 0 + ( (1) + (2) - (++i) );
//i = i = 0 + ( (1) + (2) - (3) );
//i = i = 0 + ( 3 - 3 );
//i = i = 0 + ( 0 );
//i = 0
```

Please fully parenthesize your expression. You will understand evaluation order of expression.

For your EDIT 1

```
i = i+=( (++i) + (i+=32500 + (--i) ) - (++i) ); 

// 0 + ( (++i) + (i+=32500 + (--i) ) - (++i) ); // i = 0
// 0 + ( (1) + (i+=32500 + (--i) ) - (++i) );  // i = 1
// 0 + ( (1) + (i+=32500 + (0) ) - (++i) ); // i = 0
// 0 + ( (1) + (32500 + (0) ) - (++i) );  // i = 32500
// 0 + ( (1) + (32500) - (++i) ); // i = 32500
// 0 + ( (1) + (32500) - (32501) ); // i = 32501
// 0 + ( 32501 - 32501 ); // i = 32501
// 0 // i = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I traced the value of i and here are the results:

```
i = i+=(++i + (i+=2 + --i) - ++i);
initialization: i = 0;
++i: i = 1;(1st one) and store this value
(i+=2 + --i): In it
 --i: i = 0;(i was changed by the previous ++i)
 i += 2 + 0: i = 2;(value of the inner (i+=2 + --i), store it)
++i: i = 3;
1 + 2 -3: i = 0;
i += 0: i = 0;
```

The value of the 2nd i from the left is not zero, it is the value of i after all the operations to the right are finished.

Answer (score 0):

Paranthesis takes the precedence. order would be from inner most to outermost

```
(i+=2 + --i) =>i=i+=2==(2) --2 =0 
(++i - ++i)  =>1-1=0 
i=i+ =0+0 =0
```

Each expression evaluates to 0