# Increment Operator in addition statement

Tags: php

Can anyone explain in depth why this outputs 9

here is my code in PHP:

```
$x = 4;
$x = $x+++$x++;
echo $x;
```

Comment: why are you insisting this should be tagged with `java` and `c`?

Comment: because its about order of execution not about language.

Comment: It is language-specific! Do not add tags for unrelated languages.

Comment: @Olaf Question is equally applicable to all 3 languages, the syntax is just slightly different, i.e. Java and C doesn't use `$`, is all.

Comment: I added $ to describe x is a variable.

Comment: That would not make any sense in `C` or `Java`. You should've tagged it as `php` and only `php`.

Comment: @Andreas: So it is undefined behaviour in all three languages? Then your answer is wrong and has to be downvoted.

Comment: It is undefined behaviour in C. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/153386/why-is-x-x-undefined

Comment: @Emz So you are saying that there is no increment operator in C or java :D :D

Comment: `$x+++` there is no such thing in `C` or `Java` no.

Comment: increment operator is same in java x++ + x++ gives same output in java

Comment: @AadilAli compiled as C code with MSVC, it prints `10`. You can "explain" the result of Undefined Behaviour, but it is still that.

Comment: @Olaf Sorry, was unaware that it's undefined in C. It is however very well-defined in Java.

Comment: @Emz `x = x+++x++;` is valid in Java, and behavior is well-defined.

Comment: @Andreas: Just be careful expecting the same semantics from the same syntax.

Comment: @Andreas, again, I never said it wasn't. I said that `$x+++` wasn't in either   C or Java, as far as I know it is only in php.

Comment: What is your best guess?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Execution goes like this:

```
$x = $x++ + $x++;    ($x = 4)
$x = 4 + $x++;       ($x = 5)
$x = 4 + 5;          ($x = 6)
$x = 9;
```

For a more detailed answer of a more complex example in Java, see this answer: [Incrementor logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33120663/incrementor-logic/33121756#33121756)

Comment: The variable is same why not the value change from 4 to 5 before addition ?

Comment: Value of `x` is actually `6` *right before* the addition, as I've illustrated.

Comment: Ok thank you now i understand it overwrites the value of 6