# Operator Precedence and associativity

Tags: java, operator-precedence

When an expression has two operators with the same precedence, the expression is evaluated according to its associativity. I want to know how the following works:

```
i=b + b + ++b
```

`i` here is 4
So `++b` didn't change the first 2 `b` values, but it executed first, because the execution is from left to right.

Here, however:

```
int b=1;
i= b+ ++b + ++b ;
```

`i` is 6

According to associativity, we should execute the 3rd `b` so it should be:
`1+ (++1) + ( ++1 should be done first)`.  so it becomes:
1 + ++1 + 2 =5
However, this is not right, so how does this work?

Comment: Associativity has nothing to do with order of execution. Order remain left to right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing *precedence* with *order of execution*.

Example:

```
a[b] += b += c * d + e * f * g
```

Precedence rules state that `*` comes before `+` comes before `+=`. Associativity rules (which are part of precedence rules) state that `*` is left-associative and `+=` is right-associative.

Precedence/associativity rules basically define the application of implicit parenthesis, converting the above expression into:

```
a[b] += ( b += ( (c * d) + ((e * f) * g) ) )
```

However, this expression is still *evaluated* left-to-right.

This means that the index value of `b` in the expression `a[b]` will use the value of `b` from before the `b += ...` is executed.

For a more complicated example, mixing `++` and `+=` operators, see the question [`Incrementor logic`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33120663/5221149), and the detailed [answer of how it works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33121756/5221149).

Answer (score 1):

It's correct, first b is 1, and the second b will be incremented by 1 before addition, so it's 2, and the third b is already 2, and incremented by 1 makes it 3. so It's 6 in total. The expression is evaluated from left to right as you said, thus the third b is already 2 before increment.

Comment: This is not the question, why the 2nd b executed before the 3rd b ? preincrement is right assoicative

Comment: @user1865719 no matter how it's associated, the other b will be 2 before it's own increment..

Comment: @user1865719 You are confusing *precedence* with *order of execution*.