# What are the semantics of java's postfix increment operator on the left side of an assignment statement and why do they differ from the right side?

Tags: java

I was working on a leetcode question [1] and noticed something that caught my eye.

When I write a line of code as:

```
nums[i] = nums[(i++)+count];
```

I pass all the tests and my answer is accepted. If however I change the same line to:

```
nums[i++] = nums[i+count];
```

I get an ArrayOutOfBounds exception. Why is this?

Here is the full code:

```
public void moveZeroes(int[] nums) {
    int count = 0, i = 0;
    while(i+count < nums.length){
        if(nums[i+count] == 0)
            count++;
        else
            nums[i] = nums[(i++)+count];
    }
    for(;i<nums.length; i++)
        nums[i] = 0;
}
```

[1] https://leetcode.com/problems/move-zeroes/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer lies in [JLS 15.26.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.1). Basically, this is the order of things in the case of

```
nums[i++] = nums[i+count];
```

- `nums` is evaluated (as part of the left-hand side)
- `i++` is evaluated to find the index; the result is the original value of `i`, but `i` is then incremented
- At this point, we've evaluated which array element we're assigning to
- `nums` is evaluated (as part of the right-hand side)
- `i+count` is evaluated; note that this uses the *already incremented* value of `i`, which is why you're getting an exception
- We now know which array element we're fetching
- Fetch the value of that element
- Assign the value into the LHS element we identified earlier

The important part is that the left operand of the assignment operator is evaluated *before* the expression on the right operand. So the side-effect while evaluating the array index expression in the left operand affects the evaluation of the right operand.

Comment: For a more complex example (`i = i += (++i + (i += 2 + --i) - ++i)`), see [Incrementor logic](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33120663/5221149).

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, `i` is being incremented after it is done being used in that iteration.

```
nums[(i++)+count];
```

means increment `i` by one after evaluating the equivalent of `nums[(i) + count]`.

In the second example, `i` is being incremented before `nums[ i +count];`.

```
nums[i++]
```

means increment `i` by one after evaluating the equivalent of `nums[i]`.

When the code gets to `nums[ i + count];`, `i` has already been incremented.
This is results in an ArrayOutOfBounds exception in the case that `i + count` is equal to `nums.length`.