# output of expression in ( i-- - ++i) in java

Tags: java

```
int i = 11;
    i = i-- - ++i;

    System.out.println( i-- - ++i );
```

Output:
0

Please can you people explain? 
It is really confusing

Comment: `i--` is value before decrement (11), then updates `i` to 10. `++i` increments `i` back to 11 first and result is that value. `11 - 11` is 0. Do that again for the expression in the `println()` statement, i.e. `0 - 0` is 0. If you want a more *complex* expression, see my answer to this question: [Incrementor logic](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33120663/5221149)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
i = 11;
i = i-- - ++i;
```

Before we do anything, `i` holds the value of `11`.

When we do `i--`, we actually decrease the value of `i` by `1`, but this doesn't take into effect until *after* we use it here.

```
// i = 10;
i = 11 - ++i;
```

So now `i` holds the value `10`.

Now, we subtract 10 from `++i`. Since we're pre incrementing here, `i`'s value is increased by `1` *before* we get to it.

```
// i = 11;
i = 11 - 11;
```

So now `i` holds the value `11`.

And finally, we assign `11 - 11` back to `i`.

```
// i = 0;
i = 0;
```

So we end up with a value of `0`.

Comment: @user3292797 Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

`i` starts at 11, and you "use" that value and then decrement i to 10. So your state is:

- Expression => `11 - ++i`
- i = 10

Then you increment i so your state is

- Expression => `11 - i`
- i = 11

11 - 11 = 0.

Note that in C/C++ this would be undefined behavior, but in Java it is predictable.