# How increment operator works in switch case?

Tags: java, switch-statement

It prints output from `case 10:` but prints `x=11` how? after which line it increments the value of `x`

```
int x = 10;
switch (x++) {
case 10:
        System.out.println("case 1 ::: "+x);
        break;
case 11:
    System.out.println("case 2 ::: "+x);
    break;
default:
    System.out.println("default ::: "+x);
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
case 1 ::: 11
```

Comment: Increment operator works the same way it does in all other statements. It doesn't behave different for a `switch` statement.

Comment: The value of x is used first which is 10 and it increments afterwards which becomes 11 after post increment... for better understanding read post incrementer and pre incremaentor

Comment: The increment operators are explained in the Java Tutorial, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html. Read the Fine Manual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **Post** Incremet first Switch is evaluated, then only x is incremented.
 as follows...

```
x = 10;
switch (x++){...}
```

`switch` will be evaluated First.

case 10: will be chosen. **Then only `x` will get incremented by 1** (`x` becomes 11).

Then statements in the case block get executed ( o/p will be == case 1 ::: 11)

//Hope u may get more clear, also by comparing it with **pre** increment condition

```
x = 10;
switch (++x){...}
```

**`x` will get incremented first**.(`x` becomes 11)

then switch condition get evaluated

case 11: will be chosen.

Then statements in the case block get executed ( o/p will be == case 2 ::: 11)

Answer (score 5):

The post increment operator `x++` increments `x` but returns the previous value of `x` - `10`. Therefore the `switch` statement gets the value `10` (that's the value of the `x++` expression), and executes the block of `case 10:`, at which point `System.out.println("case 1 ::: "+x);` prints the incremented value of `x` - `11`.

Answer (score 1):

Your question *"after which line it increments the value of x?"* show where you're totally missing the point of the increment operator.

It **immediately** increments the value. The increment is not *deferred* until the end of any statement.

E.g. if `x = 10`, the statement `y = x++ + x++ + x++` will calculate `y = 10 + 11 + 12` and result in `y = 33` and `x = 13`.

In contrast, the statement `y = ++x + ++x + ++x` will calculate `y = 11 + 12 + 13` and result in `y = 36` and `x = 13`.

As you can see, both post-increment and pre-increment operators will immediately affect the value of the variable being incremented. The difference is whether the *expression* uses the value before (pre) or after (post) the increment.

For a more complex example, see this answer: [Incrementor logic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33121756/5221149)

Comment: if it immediately increases x's value then why it selects case 10:?

Comment: Because the expression uses the *before*-increment value. If you want the *after*-increment value, use `++x`, not `x++`. That's the difference between the two.

Answer (score 0):

X++ is a post-incrementation. As such, the initial value of x (10) is taken for the switch, and then and only then it is incremented.

This is why your have case 1 and then 11

Answer (score 0):

The `switch` statement gets evaluated with `x=10` which matches the case 1 and the post increment operator increments its value by 1 at the same time and so `x` becomes `11`. That's why you are getting the result `case 1 ::: 11`

Comment: so it is not evaluated with --> switch(x++) ??

Comment: you have a post increment operator there it follows the principle *Use then Change*. It uses the initial value of x (i.e 10) and updates it to 11 immediately.