# what pre and post increment in java is used for except for (shorthand,getting value before increment or after increment)?

Tags: java, operators

I know that pre and post increment(like `++i, i++, --i, i--`) used for shorthand, getting value before increment or after increment. this can be achieved with other methods too . but, Do they have another additional advantage?

Comment: Are you familiar with the `Unary` & `Binary` Operators?

Comment: @user2004685 yes

Comment: Note you can also do the same thing with `i += 1` or `i -= 1`.

Comment: No, there shouldn't be any other advantage after the JIT has the chance to work over the code.  They'll get compiled down to the same thing.

Comment: @LouisWasserman while you code, is there any situation you prefer i++ over i=i+1, for some advantage except shorthand

Comment: I think one advantage is that many C programmers were familiar with pre- and post-increment, so having them available in Java eased adoption.  They're also a handy and compact shorthand once you get used to them.

Comment: @FredK i know but while you code, is there any situation you prefer i++ over i=i+1, for some advantage except shorthand

Comment: @TheScientificMethod Array indexing is a common usage for pre- and post-increment `s[i++] = m[j++];`

Comment: @markspace Well you can do it  like also s[i+1] = m[j+1], still no advantage except shorthand

Comment: Those are not equivalent because the values of `i` or `j` wouldn't update.

Comment: @TheScientificMethod Right, what Mick said.  What you wrote and what I wrote are totally different.  Your code computes `i+1` but does nothing else.  `i++` uses `i`'s current value (not i+1) and then afterwards increments the value of `i` for all future calculations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, what are the differences between:

- `x++`
- `++x`
- `x += 1`
- `x = x + 1`

As mentioned by [Louis Wasserman in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51956072/what-pre-and-post-increment-in-java-is-used-for-except-for-shorthand#comment90862836_51956072):

> There shouldn't be any other advantage after the JIT has the chance to work over the code. They'll get compiled down to the same thing.

This is however only a true statement if the 4 are used as standalone *statements*. All 4 of them can also be used as an *expression*, in which case they are not all the same:

- `a = x++` is the value *before* incrementing `x`.
- `a = ++x`, `a = x += 1`, and `a = x = x + 1` are all the value *after* incrementing `x`.

Also, `x = x + 1` evaluates `x` twice, while the other 3 only evaluates it once. For a simple `x` that makes no difference, but for e.g. an array lookup `a[k]` that makes a difference, especially if "k" can change.

Example:

```
// setup
int[] a = { 5, 15, 25 };
int k = 0;

// result of each if run right after setup
a[k++]++;            // k = 1, a = [6, 15, 25]
++a[k++];            // k = 1, a = [6, 15, 25]
a[k++] += 1;         // k = 1, a = [6, 15, 25]

a[++k]++;            // k = 1, a = [5, 16, 25]
a[k+=1]++;           // k = 1, a = [5, 16, 25]
a[k=k+1]++;          // k = 1, a = [5, 16, 25]

a[k++] = a[k++] + 1; // k = 2, a = [16, 15, 25]
```

Now, that last one is a doozie. For a long explanation of how that works, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33121756/5221149), but it evaluates left-to-right:

```
k = 0;    a[k++] = a[k++] + 1;
k = 1;    a[0] = a[k++] + 1;
k = 2;    a[0] = a[1] + 1;
k = 2;    a[0] = 15 + 1;
k = 2;    a[0] = 16;
```

**To recap:**

- There is no difference if run as a statement, and `x` has no side-effects (very common).
- As an expression, the `x++` post-increment evaluates to a different value.
- `x = x + 1` evaluates `x` twice, which matters if `x` has side-effects (rare).

Other than that, it is a matter of choice which to use.

---

**Bytecode**

For those curious about bytecode, using Eclipse compiler, if "x" is a simple variable, all 4 as statements compiles to

```
iinc          1, 1
```

As expressions with simple variables, e.g. `y = x++`, they compile differently:

```
// y = x++;
iload_2
iinc          2, 1
istore_1

// y = ++x;   y = x += 1;   y = x = x + 1;
iinc          2, 1
iload_2
istore_1
```

With array:

```
// y = a[k]++;
aload_1
iload_2
dup2
iaload
dup_x2
iconst_1
iadd
iastore
istore_3

// y = ++a[k];   y = a[k] += 1;
aload_1
iload_2
dup2
iaload
iconst_1
iadd
dup_x2
iastore
istore_3

// y = a[k] = a[k] + 1;
aload_1
iload_2
aload_1
iload_2
iaload
iconst_1
iadd
dup_x2
iastore
istore_3
```

Comment: Why would `x` be evaluated multiple times? Could you print out the bytecode from your examples?

Comment: @Kayaman In `x = x + 1`, the sub-expression "x" is evaluated twice because the language defines it so. As a simple variable, e.g. "x" is `i`, as in `i = i + 1`, you'd never notice, but if "x" is `a[k++]`, it makes a huge difference, as explicitly covered in my answer.

Comment: Ah yes of course with a more complicated expression it makes sense. I was just wondering whether that double evaluation would show up in the bytecode.

Comment: @Kayaman Added examples of how bytecode is different in some cases. With array, the double evaluation shows up.

Comment: Thanks. So `y = ++x;   y = x += 1;   y = x = x + 1;` are equivalent in the bytecode, the more complex expressions obviously not.

Comment: @Andreas  while you actually code, was there any situation you prefer `i++` over `i=i+1` or `x += 1`, to reduce multiple evaluations . `x ` is a variable in the right hand, what do you mean `x` is evaluated multiple times?

Comment: @TheScientificMethod The reason I used "x" instead of `i`, is because "x" is a placeholder which *can* be just a variable, but can also be an array cell, as illustrated in the answer. Try reading the answer in full. --- I **always** prefer `i++` over `i += 1` and `i = i + 1`, especially in `for` loops, because of brevity and it shows intent, i.e. increment to *next* value, for integers anyway. I probably wouldn't use it for `double` (or `float`), but then again, I can't remember ever having to *increment* a floating-point variable by 1.