# Does brackets matter in a combination of post decrement or increment like this one: x+=(x++)+(++x);

Tags: java, increment, decrement

For the following program is it necessary to have the brackets in the statement of post-increment or decrement

```
public class sample
{
  public void f1()
  {
    int x=4;
    x+=(x++)+(++x);
System.out.println(x);
  }
}
```

^^Is this equal to

```
public class sample
{
  public void f1()
  {
    int x=4;
    x+= x++ + ++x;
System.out.println(x);
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Incrementor logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33120663/incrementor-logic)

Comment: You only need the brackets surrounding `++x`

Comment: Did you even try running `x+=x+++++x;` ?  It doesn't work.

Comment: sure, at the very least for reading (could use spaces too).. .speaking of which, why would someone write such code (if not to confuse any reader)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessary to use brackets.  Both prefix and postfix `++` have a higher precedence than `+`.

However, it is necessary to use something to separate the `++` and `+` operators.  If you don't separate them (with whitespace, comments or other tokens) you get a rather confused compilation error.  For example:

```
Test.java:3: error: unexpected type
    int j = i +++++ i;
              ^
  required: variable
  found:    value
1 error
```

Here's what is going on:

1. The lexical analyser reads the above as `int j = i ++ ++ + i ;`.  This is a consequence of [JLS 3.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.12):

   > *"The longest possible translation is used at each step, even if the result does not ultimately make a correct program while another lexical translation would."*
2. Taking precedence into account, the parser parses the expression as:

   ```
                +
               / \
             ++   i
             /
           ++
           /
          i
   ```

   where `++` is the postfix increment operator.  That is equivalent to `((i++)++) + i`.
3. The analyser detects that postfix `++` is being applied to the result of `i++`, which is a value.  That is illegal.  The operand of `++` has to be variable not a value.

   As [JLS 15.14.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.14.2) says:

   > *"The result of the [operand] must be a variable of a type that is convertible to a numeric type, or a compile-time error occurs."*

---

But seriously, don't write code like this. It is just confusing ... and unnecessary.

Comment: It tokenizes as `i ++ ++ + i` and parses as `((i++)++)+i`. `i++` is the unexpected value which can't be (re-)incremented.

Comment: Ah yes, I see.  So it is tokenizing, but the heuristic the JLS has specified gives a token sequence that doesn't make sense to the analyser.  The inner `(i++)` needs to be an *lvalue*, not just any old expression.

Answer (score 0):

There’s no need for parentheses but you do need to separate the `+`s.

Java uses *maximal munch* when parsing. That means it consumes as much of the text as it can to make tokens.

So, for example,

`+++++`

is parsed as

`++ ++ +`

and that makes no sense (the post increment result is not an *l-value*) so the compiler issues a diagnostic.

With `++ + ++` the normal grouping rules apply (informally speaking, operator precedence), so the entire expression is grouped as you have it in the first snippet you present.

Answer (score 0):

You should not wrote code like this. I cannot think of any use of this and it is confusing for the reader.

The answer can be found easily by writing some test code, but it does not matter.